# How to select all files in a folder Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to select all files in images folder, instead of listing them one by one

```
        function initPage() {
            var pairsGame = new PairsGame({
                containerId: 'playfield',
                cardWidth: 200,
                cardHeight: 150,
                cols: 4,
                rows: 3,
                imageBase: 'images/',
                images: ['abendwolken.jpg','herd.jpg','muellkatze.jpg',
                    'ich_in_berlin.jpg','schaedel.jpg','sonnenblume.jpg',
                    'duenenbier.jpg','igel.jpg','schlafkatze.jpg',
                    'sunset.jpg']
```

Answer (score 2):

unless you're using node or something similar JS does not generally have access the filesystem.

however there are some exceptions... 
The HTML5 FileAPI for example
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0):

```
 var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog( "Please select top level folder to process"); 
    var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles();

    for(i=0;i<fileList.length;i++) var docRef = app.open(fileRef);
```

Comment: Provide some explanation, so that future user can understand easily.!!